# Installing ffmpeg in Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So as the title says I am trying to install ffmpeg package on amazon linux.

I tried the commands:

```
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm 
sudo rpm -Uhv rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uhv rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install ffmpeg
```

but I got the following error:

```
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libpulse-simple.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libva.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libtheoradec.so.1(libtheoradec_1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.0(CDIO_CDDA_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libopenal.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libtheoraenc.so.1(libtheoraenc_1.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_cdda.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libpulse.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libtheoradec.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libass.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libpulse.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libgsm.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libtheoraenc.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcelt0.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libpulse-simple.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libcdio_paranoia.so.0(CDIO_PARANOIA_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libv4l2.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: ffmpeg-libs-0.10.15-1.el6.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libdc1394.so.22()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no experience with rpm, but if you don't need any special libraries compiled with ffmpeg, you could also just download a static build and use that: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used commands from [this guide](http://www.spidersoft.com.au/2014/ffmpeg-on-ami-linux-and-centos-the-easy-way/), but this method doesn't work.
This error happens because Amazon Linux doesn't include most multimedia libs including ffmpeg, Pulse and so on. You need to add CentOS repos, which contain these missing packages.

I had the same error and this is how I dealt with it.

1. Create repo-file where you should include CentOS repos **of proper version**.This is important!
    If your AMI EPEL repos have 6th version, then use CentOS 6. If 7th, then CentOS 7.

   ```
   [base]
   name=CentOS-6 - Base
   mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os
   #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/extras/x86_64/
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
   priority=1
   [updates]
   name=CentOS-6 - Updates
   mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=updates
   #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
   priority=1
   [extras]
   name=CentOS-6 - Extras
   mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=extras
   #baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/extras/x86_64/
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
   priority=1
   #additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
   ```
2. Import GPG key for the repo

   ```
   sudo rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
   ```
3. Update repos

   ```
   yum -y update --skip-broken
   ```
4. Install ffmpeg as usual

   ```
   yum install ffmpeg
   ```

The method was taken [from this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=196807) and a bit adapted to be more up to date.

**UPDATE**: The FFmpeg was removed from CentOS Extras repo, since CentOS 7 you should pick it from [Nux](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/) or [Okey](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/okey-x86_64/) repo

Comment: This also needs the nux dextop repo now as ffmpeg is not included in centos repo anymore https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-centos

Comment: Thanks for noting